# send message from AppleWatch to iPhone app using watchOS2

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I tried to send message to iPhone app from iwatchExtension(on ButtonClick) using `WCSession` method like

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:applicationData
                                   replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply)
```

But delegate method 
 `- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:` is not getting called.

when I tried same while passing data from iPhone to iWatch, it works properly. All delegate methods get called properly in "Extension Delegate" class.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the definition of `WCSession` delegate methods you will find a minor difference about their receiving nature. Check the bold quote.

> /** Called on the delegate of the receiver. Will be called on startup
>   if the incoming message caused the receiver to launch. */
>   - (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary *)message;
>
> /** Called on the delegate of the receiver **when the sender sends a
>   message that expects a reply**. Will be called on startup if the
>   incoming message caused the receiver to launch. */
>   - (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary *)message
>   replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary
>   *replyMessage))replyHandler;

As you are providing a non-null parameter for `replyHandler:`, you should be receiving the message in other delegate i.e.  `-(void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message`.

You are using [WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage: ...] for communication, which lacks the delegate assignment plus you have not activated the session.

In your Extention class, create an ivar for `WCSession` and write this code

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    // Configure interface objects here.    
    if([WCSession isSupported])
    {
        session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }    
}
```

and then send message like `[session sendMessage:applicationData replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply)`.

In your `AppDelegate.m` file just create and instance of `WCSession` and activate it and use the correct `delegate` method to capture the message.

```
if([WCSession isSupported]) {
     appSession = [WCSession defaultSession];
     appSession.delegate = self;
     [appSession activateSession];
}
```

I believe this should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this,
//*
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler {

*//

Also tried,

//*
    - (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveUserInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)userInfo

*//


But same issue, delegate method not get called in iphone side.

Comment: Can you post some more code from both iWatch & iPhone side. To be specific i wanna know how you are calling from iPhone. As you are not assigning the `delegate` object of `defaultSession` in this case and also not activating it. Try as `session = [WCSession defaultSession];  session.delegate = self;  [session activateSession];` and then `[session sendMessage: ...];`

Comment: On Button Clicked Method I tried

     NSString *counterString = /*my data*/
    NSDictionary *applicationData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[counterString] forKeys:@[@"counterValue"]];
    
    [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:applicationData
                               replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {}
                               errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {} ];

Also,
 [[WCSession defaultSession] transferUserInfo:@{@"WatchTaskListClicked":@"YES"}];
 
On iPhone Side -  in AppDelegate 
I just tried to receive message with all delegate methods of WCSession

Comment: Also In Extension Class

I wrote
**
 - (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {

    if(WCSession.isSupported) {
        WCSession* session = WCSession.defaultSession;
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }
}**

Comment: Delete these messages and include all the relevant code in your question. Check if my updated answer solve your problem.